# Format cell, If word from list in cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-custom-function, regexextract

**I'm trying to color tag cells according to keywords they may contain.** I've searched just about everywhere, and have tried various applications of the Search and Find functions to no avail.

**Imagine I have the following cells:**

```
[You] [ggg] [123]
```

**and I want to highlight only the cells that contain:**

```
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

**What custom formula would I use to format only the cells containing numbers? Highlighting:**

```
123
```

**This should work as well for:**

```
[yes] [nah] [yah]
affirmativeResponses = [yes,yah,ya,yup]
highlights: yes, yah
```

**Pseudo code:**

```
for i in [yes,yah,ya,yup]:
    if i in cell:
        highlight(cell, green)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- for all numbers:

  ```
  =IF(ISNUMBER(A1), 1)
  ```

  [image: 0]

---

- for specific digits (2 and 3):

  ```
  =REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1), "2|3")
  ```

  [image: 0]

---

- for exact words:

  ```
  =REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "yes|nah|yah")
  ```

  [image: 0]

---

- for partial (containing) matches:

  ```
  =REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "yes|nah|yah")
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: Wow, great answer. Thank you for such a comprehensive answer!